# How to define different timeouts for resources in Trajectory? simmer/DES

Tags: r

How can I define different timeouts for various resources in Trajectory (simmer for R) in DES? 
The below code generates activity time for "doctor1", "doctor2" and "doctor3" as the same i.e. mean=5, sd=.5 Normal RV. 
Require mean=5, sd=.5 for doctor 1; mean=10, sd=.5 for doctor 2 and mean=20, sd=.5 for doctor 3. How this can be achieved?

```
patient_traj <- trajectory(name = "patient_trajectory") %>%
  select(resources = c("doctor1", "doctor2", "doctor3")) %>%
  set_capacity_selected(1) %>%
  seize_selected(amount = 1) %>%
  timeout(function() rnorm(1, 5, .5)) %>%
  release_selected(amount = 1)

env <- simmer() %>%
  add_resource("doctor1", capacity = 0) %>%
  add_resource("doctor2", capacity = 0) %>%
  add_resource("doctor3", capacity = 0) %>%
  add_generator("patient", patient_traj, function() rnorm(1,2,.8),mon = 2) %>%
  run(500)

arrival <- get_mon_arrivals(env, per_resource = T)
```

Require mean=5, sd=.5 for doctor 1; mean=10, sd=.5 for doctor 2 and mean=20, sd=.5 for doctor 3. i.e. different timeouts showing performance difference among doctors

Comment: While simmer (and presumably Trajectory) may be a Discrete-Event Simulation (DES) package for R, it's not applicable to the the [tag:des] which stands for Data Encryption Standard (DES).

Answer (score 0):

You may use `get_selected()`, but generally speaking, if you want different things to happen, it's better to use a `branch()` with several paths.